# Как отправить смс через mcommunicator API?

Tags: api, sms

Собственно я знаю ответ ... обратитесь в техподдержку МТС, дааа... но я тоже могу предложить обратиться вас в их техподдержку, чтобы узнать почему я задаю вопрос тут.

Собственно как отправить смс через их API? документация типа https://mcommunicator.ru/M2M/m2m_api.asmx?op=SendMessage не работает. Собственно логин и пароль и остальные согласованные с мтс данные, введённые в форме - примере там же - тупо пишет ту же ошибку, что и мои скрипты INCORRECT_PASSWORD. Скрипты, которые ранее, работали нормально.

Собственно вопрос 1 есть где документация по настройке отправки смс через их API?

Может кто выложить POST запрос, который приводит к отправке сообщения, вырезав данные своего аккаунта?

Comment: По вашей ссылке есть тестовая форма. Откройте `консоль браузера->network(сеть)` и отправте форму. Потом найдите этот самый запрос в таблице `network` и напишите "на подобии" со своими данными.

Answer (score 1):

Вот рабочий пример

```
$pass = 'token-api';
$login = ''; 
$naming = 'name';
$msid = '79201234567';
$message = 'сообщение';

$sURL = "https://api.mcommunicator.ru/M2M/m2m_api.asmx/SendMessage"; // URL-адрес POST 
$sPD = "msid=".$msid."&message=".$message."&naming=".$naming."&login=".$login."&password=".$pass; // Данные POST
$aHTTP = array(
  'http' => 
    array(
    'method'  => 'POST', 
    'content' => $sPD
  )
);
$context = stream_context_create($aHTTP);
$contents = file_get_contents($sURL, false, $context);
```

Да, логин должен быть пустым.

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Через SOAP, работает 100%.

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://www.mcommunicator.ru/m2m/m2m_api.asmx?wsdl",
[
    "trace"      => 1,
    "exceptions" => 0
]);
$result = $client->SendMessage(
[
    "login" => "",//да, логина не надо
    "password" => "token",
    "msid" => "7**********",
    "message" => "Привет, как дела? Отправил программно :-)",
]);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
print "Request :\n".($client->__getLastRequest()) ."\n";
print "Response:\n".($client->__getLastResponse())."\n";
echo '</pre>';
```